# Asynchronous Call to Read returns immediately

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I've been trying to use boost in order to asynchronously read from a `serial_port` until it puts incoming data into a buffer that I have specified.  However, when I call:

```
boost::asio::async_read(*port_, 
                        *readBuf_,
                        boost::bind(&Serial::async_read_handler, 
                                    this, 
                                    boost::asio::placeholders::error, 
                                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

it calls `async_read_handler` immediately, which triggers the code inside my `read_handler`.

```
void Serial::async_read_handler(const boost::system::error_code &e, 
                                std::size_t bytes_read)
{
    namespace basio = boost::asio;
    if(!e)
    {
        std::cout << e.message() << std::endl;
        std::cout << bytes_read << std::endl;

        if(bytes_read <= 0)
        {
            std::string read = *basio::buffer_cast<std::string*>(*readBuf_);
            std::cout << read << std::endl;
            basio::async_read(*port_, 
                              *readBuf_, 
                              boost::bind(&Serial::async_read_handler, 
                                          this, 
                                          basio::placeholders::error, 
                                          basio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        else
        {
            std::string read = *basio::buffer_cast<std::string*>(*readBuf_);
            std::cout << read << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Bytes read: " << bytes_read << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << e.message() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I first call a thread to run `async_read` in my main

```
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    Serial::Serial serial(PORT, &io);
    if(!serial.is_open())
    {
        serial.open(PORT);
    }
    serial.async_read();
    io.run();
    return 0;
}
```

I want the `async_read` call to wait until it has read data from the buffer to call the handler.  How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe there is already data buffered for the callback to extract?

Comment: Do you have an error code in the read handler ? If not do you have data ?

Comment: I do not have an error code in the read handler.  I know this because when I print e.message it is undefined

Comment: I will check that there is no data already in the buffer, but I' m 99% positive that there is not

Comment: No bytes are transferred during the async read operation